# C# Silverlight get frequency of sound

Tags: c#, silverlight, audio, byte, arrays

I've been trying to use some code like the following to read current sound from the mic

_Capture is a `CaptureSource` and _Encoder is a `SimpleAudioEncoder` (Custom class)

```
_Capture = new CaptureSource();
_Encoder = new SimpleAudioEncoder(this);
_Encoder.CaptureSource = _Capture;

if (_Capture != null)
{
    _Capture.AudioCaptureDevice = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultAudioCaptureDevice();
    CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultAudioCaptureDevice();
    if (CaptureDeviceConfiguration.AllowedDeviceAccess || CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("_Capture.Start()");
        _Capture.Start();
    }
}
```

Definition of `SimpleAudioEncoder`

```
public class SimpleAudioEncoder : AudioSink
{
    public SimpleAudioEncoder() {

    }
    protected override void OnCaptureStarted()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnCaptureStopped()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnFormatChange(
    AudioFormat audioFormat) {

    }

    protected override void OnSamples(
    long sampleTimeInHundredNanoseconds,
    long sampleDurationInHundredNanoseconds,
    byte[] sampleData)
    {

    }
}
```

Im guessing that the `sampleData` `byte[]` array has the data I'm looking for but how can I use it to find the frequency of the sound?

It would be great if I could find a function like

`public double GetFreq(byte[] data)`

To use like

`double hertz = GetFreq(sampleData)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Establishing the frequency of the sound requires converting the signal from the time domain to the frequency domain. It will involve [Fourier transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) and subsequent analysis of the output. It's really not a job for anyone without a pretty thorough understanding of DSP techniques. If you have to ask, then you're a long way from being able to implement this yourself. I'd recommend a third party library.

[This page](http://bonkel.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/frequency-detection-using-fourier-transform/) gives a fairly good view from somebody new to frequency detection.

Comment: What are some third party libraries?

Comment: Also could I be able to use this Fourier Transform Class http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=20025 Click on FourierTansform.cs

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847633/net-library-to-identify-pitches/1847723 as this is mainly going to require number-crunching you can do in Silverlight.